# How to read "BSON"?

Tags: acronyms, computing, reading

BSON is a particular data format used in web development, derived from the JSON format. JSON is pronounced "jay-son" as the Greek hero, and given the tendendcy the scientific community has to have interesting names, I suspect "BSON" is read as "bison", and not as "bee-son". But, I have no motherlanguage computer scientist nearby to sustain my theory.  Which is right?

Comment: According to Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSON it is actually pronounced"bee-son"

Comment: it's seems that beeson should be the right way to pronounce it.

Comment: Actually, there's no agreement as to how to pronounce "JSON".  I've heard it pronounced both "Jason" (as in the Argonaut) and "jay-sahn".

Comment: As in the *anglicized* version of the name of the leader of the Argonauts, that is.  Apollonius Rhodius gives the name as Ἰήσων *(Iḗsōn),* Euripides as Ἰάσων *(Iásōn).*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSON it is actually pronounced"bee-son". And the same pronunciation is espoused by the specification page http://bsonspec.org/

Answer (score 4):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSON) suggests it is "bee-son": *BSON /ˈbiːsɒn/ is* [as **i:** is pronounced as the *ee* in **see**.](http://www.antimoon.com/how/pronunc-soundsipa.htm)

Comment: Ha, i really missed that Wikipedia had pronunciation suggestions!

Comment: @piffy Hey! I answered first! Can I at least get an upvote!!??! ;-)

Comment: +1. Been there, buddy. The sad part is that early answers show lower in the queue. But, I must add, try not to answer basic and gen-ref questions too much. It's bad for the site. Cheers.

Comment: @Peter K. - Sorry about that, Peter. I can't upvote, I'm too "young" for that.